# Unique Title value in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

I defined a custom list, and there was a column named **Title**, the **SharePoint standard column**. I wanted to make Title value be **unique**. I have set `Indexed` and `EnforceUniqueValues` as `TRUE`, but it doesn't work. What settings should I do in the **scheme.xml** with no coding works? I'm using Sandbox Solution.

By the way, I can set unique value on other columns I defined by these settings in scheme.xml.

I guess I need to modify the definition of the `content type`, but `Title` column is in `List Content Type`, I cannot modify it. Or do you know how to get the `scheme.xml` that modified by settings in web?

Comment: Are you editing the sceme.xml ?? How about modify the values through web administration ?

Comment: I can set this via list setting in web. But I want to achieve it in scheme.xml, then I don't need to set it when I deploy the solution.

Comment: @rolivares I can set this via list setting in web. But I want to achieve it in scheme.xml, then I don't need to set it when I deploy the solution.

Answer (score 0):

but you can achieve that using visual studio and creating an template list and list instance , avoiding the direct schemme modification. More simple and fast. I've created list and unique reatrictions using that approach.

Comment: Could you please show me the scheme.xml of your list definition? Thank you!

Comment: Did you mean set `Indexed` and `EnforceUniqueVues` as `TRUE` for the field in Scheme.xml?